# Stubbing Angular2 responses for local development

Tags: angular

In angular1 I was able to use $httpBackend to stub/mock http calls when I was developing locally. It would go a little something like this:

```
$httpBackend
  .whenGET('/api/v1/accounts/ticker')
  .respond({data: [1,2,3]})
```

How do I go about doing something similar for local development in Angular2?

Comment: Is using Node and Express a viable option for you? This  way you can quickly create your local full-fledged Rest server and call Rest services from your App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**update**

```
describe('...', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestComponent],
      providers: [
        MockBackend
        {provide: XHRBackend, useExisting: MockBackend},
        {provide: JSONPBackend, useExisting: MockBackend}
      ],
      imports: [HttpModule]
    });
  });

  it('...', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
  });
});
```

**original**

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS, 
    provide(XHRBackend, {useClass: MockBackend}),
    provide(JSONPBackend, {useClass: MockBackend})]);
```

Then inject `MockBackend` and use it like

```
backend.connections.subscribe(c => connection = c);
  http.request('data.json').subscribe((res) => {
    expect(res.text()).toBe('awesome');
    async.done();
  });
  connection.mockRespond(new Response('awesome'));
```

You can inject it in a component or after bootstrap like

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS, 
    provide(XHRBackend, {useClass: MockBackend}),
    provide(JSONPBackend, {useClass: MockBackend})])
.then((componentRef: ComponentRef) => {
  let injector = componentRef.injector;
  let backend = injector.get(MockBackend);
  backend.connections.subscribe(connection => {
    if(connection.request ...) {
      connection.mockRespond(new Response('awesome'));      
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I can't get this to work with the current 2.0.0 release. Have you got it working with this?